# Clarification about light sensor dimensionality on different Android devices

Tags: android

I am developing an app that uses several sensors data, one of them is ambiental light.

As specified in Android Documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_environment) I read event.values[0] in sensor's listener when new data is available.

However I noticed that some devices have also values for event.values[1] and event.values[2] causing data to be potentially multidimensional.

I searched a lot but I haven't found answers, someone can explain me if values with index 1 and 2 are relevant and the reason because they exist.

Answer (score 0):

The light intensity values in lux are reported by the first element in the array. The extra values reported by some devices are not truly relevant to raw light intensity. In my limited experience and testing it looked to me that the extra values were present on some devices with RGB light meters.